# NSLogWriter ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: exception, xamarin.ios, arguments, range, stringbuilder

As you can see in the attached screenshot, I am checking the length of sb and if it's not 0, it will execute the Replace command.

However, somehow the Length is zero and it is executing the Replace command and throwing an exceptiong.  But there is content in '_str', so I don't understand how the length could be zero...

Is this a bug in StringBuilder?

[image]

Below is another bug, probably related to the one above.  You can see that I commented out the Replace command and now it is failing on ToString().

[image]

Comment: are you initializing "sb" somewhere?  I see a declaration but no initialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you using `NSLogWriter` ? Like this (see my [blog](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/ios-5-1-vs-stdout/)):

```
Console.SetOut (new NSLogWriter ());
Console.WriteLine ("we're back in action!");
```

or are you creating (and using) your own instance ? e.g.

```
var log = new NSLogWriter ();
log.WriteLine ("uho");
```

If you use the second way then you need to handle multithreading yourself. E.g. another log could have flushed (and cleared `sb`) between the `Length` check and the `Replace` call.

`System.Console` avoids this because the `NSLogWriter` is wrapped with [`TextWriter.Synchronized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter.synchronized.aspx), e.g. something similar to:

```
stdout = new NSLogWriter ();
stdout = TextWriter.Synchronized (stdout);
```

Comment: I am using Console.SetOut(new NSLogWriter()); in the initialization section of my main code loop.  Thereafter, I just use Console.WriteLine() in the various threads in my app.

Comment: You do not need to do this with recent MonoTouch versions as they include an internal and updated version of `NSLogWriter`. If you want to use the older one (from my blog) or a custom one then you'll need to call `TextWriter.Synchronized` on it before passing it to `Console.SetOut`.

Comment: I'm just trying to use the code from your blog.  Are you saying that Console.WriteLine should work in newer versions of MonoTouch (starting with which version?) without me creating or calling NSLogWriter in my code?  If I do need to include some NSLogWriter code, is your blog post still accurate? Thanks!

Comment: Only the recent 5.3 (beta) versions has the `NSLogWriter` built-in. If you're running on 5.2.x then you still need to create an `NSLogWriter` instance and call `TextWriter.Synchronized` on it **before** calling `Console.SetOut`

Comment: Got it.  I'm still on 5.2.12 waiting for the memory leak issue to be resolved (any progress on that?).  I added a call to Synchronized as shown in your post above and it seems to have done the trick.  Thanks!